# Consistently receiving user input through a long-running procedure (DoEvents or otherwise)

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Cleanly cancelling a long API-Ridden procedure is hellish, and I'm attempting to work out the best way to navigate the hellishness.

I'm using excel 2016 (with manual calculations and no screen updates) - I may take some time to attempt to run the procedure on 2010 to see if any issues resolve in the coming days (I'm aware of the slowdowns).

Over time, my procedure `LongProcedure` has lost its ability to successfully use its cancel feature (presumably due to increasing complexity). It was initially inconsistent and required significant spam-clicking to cancel, and now it fails altogether

Here's the setup:
First, `LongProcedure` is in a class module `LongClass` with a public property checked against for early cancelling, allowing it to clean up.

```
Public Sub LongProcedure()
    ' [Set up some things] '
    For Each ' [Item In Some Large Collection (Est. 300 Items)] '
        ' [Some Code (ETA 5 Seconds) Sprinkled with 3-4 DoEvents] '
        ' [Export workbook (ETA 10 Seconds)] '
        If (cancelLongProcedure) Then Exit For
    Next
    ' [Clean up some things] '
    GeneratorForm.Reset ' Let the UserForm know we're finished
End Sub
```

Second, I have a UserForm shown from a macro, which instantiates the procedure class, and runs the procedure. It contains a run button, a status label, and a cancel button.

```
Private MyLong As LongClass

Public Sub ButtonRunLongProcedure_Click()
    Set myLong = New LongClass
    myLong.LongProcedure()
End Sub
```

So the issue overall is twofold.
The `ExportAsFixedFormat` call opens a "Publishing..." progress bar which freezes excel for around ten seconds - fine. In all of my efforts, I haven't found a single way to process user input while this is happening.
On top of this, the `DoEvents` calls seemingly no longer do anything to allow the cancel button to be clicked. The process inconsistently freezes excel, tabs into other open programs, and (when not freezing) updates the status label.

**I've Tried:**

- Appending DoEvents to the `SetStatusLabel` method instead of sprinkling - while the form still often freezes, it otherwise updates the status label consistently (while still not allowing the cancel button)
- Using winAPI `Sleep` in place of, and in addition to `DoEvents` with delays of 1, 5, 10, 50, and 250ms - The form simply stopped updating at all without doevents, and with both it froze more.
- Using a `Do While` loop to run `DoEvents` constantly for one second (Froze)
- Overriding QueryClose to cancel the form. This one helped significantly. For some reason, the close [x] button can be clicked *far* more consistently than the userform buttons - Still not as consistently as I'd like. The problem? during publishing, Excel stops responding, and as such, modern windows will end the process if you click the close button twice... without cleanup.
- Using Application.OnTime to regularly call DoEvents. Didn't seem to improve the situation overall
- Alt-Tabbing. No, really. for some reason, while alt-tabbing occasionally just makes the UserForm freeze harder, sometimes it makes it stop freezing and update.

This is an issue I'm willing to do significant refactor work for, including smashing up the idea of the long procedure into separate methods, performing setup initially, and cleanup on class termination. I'm looking for *something* that provides consistent results. - I'll accept anything from excel versions to excel settings to refactors to winAPI calls.

Thanks for any insight into this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out simply combining together some of the useful improvements, along with a new one, made all the difference.

- QueryClose is up to personal preference. Leave it in to catch more terminations, leave it out to ensure users use the new solution
- Stick to sprinkling `doEvents` in places you feel are logical (not just when the status bar updates - like before and after an `Application.Calculate` call)
- Optimize the long-running process as best you can, avoiding excel calls

And, most significantly

- The integrated cancel key feature (`CTRL+Break` by default) is significantly more responsive than UserForm buttons *and* the form close button, *without* the chance of accidentally ending the excel task.

**Here's the process to polish that for a finished product**

First, set up a `debugMode`, or the inverse `handleErrors`, module-level variable to control whether to implement break-to-cancel and error handling. (Error handling will make your code harder to debug, so you'll appreciate the switch)

If your process is handling errors, you'll set `Application.EnableCancelKey` to `xlErrorHandler`, and `On Error GoTo [ErrorHandlingLabel]`. The error handling label should be directly before cleanup, and immediately set `EnableCancelKey` to `xlDisabled` to avoid bugs. Your handler should check the stored `Err.Number` and act accordingly, before continuing on to the cleanup steps.

Ensure that if you defer to any other complex vba in your script (such as using `Application.Calculate` on a sheet with UDFs), you set `On Error GoTo 0` beforehand, and `On Error GoTo [ErrorHandlingLabel]` after, to avoid catching cellbound errors.

Unfortunately, the drawback is that for the UX to be consistently readable, you'll have to leave the cancel key on `xlDisabled` until the form is closed.

**And in code:**

```
Public Sub LongProcedure()
    If handleErrors Then
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
        Application.EnableCancelKey = xlErrorHandler
    End If
    ' [Set up some things] '
    For Each ' [Item In Some Large Collection (Est. 300 Items)] '
        ' [Some Code (ETA 5 Seconds) Sprinkled with 3-4 DoEvents] '
        ' [Export workbook (ETA 10 Seconds)] '
    Next
ErrorHandler:
    If handleErrors Then
        Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
        If (Err.Number <> 0 And Err.Number <> 18) Then
            MsgBox Err.Description, vbOKOnly, "Error " & CStr(Err.Number)
        End If
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
    ' [Clean up some things] '
    GeneratorForm.Reset ' Let the UserForm know we're finished
End Sub
```

and in the UserForm

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If MyLong.handleErrors Then Application.EnableCancelKey = xlInterrupt
End Sub
```

A small note that **this method will likely generate a few bugs** you weren't expecting to encounter because the execution jumps *directly* to the specified label. Your cleanup code will need to have required variables instantiated from the start.

Overall, once these issues are fixed, this setup ensures that the user can click `CTRL+Break` as many times as they could possibly want without causing crashes or popups.